# Rails form submit returns javascript, but script is output in browser vs. executed

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form:

```
<%= form_tag('quote/price', method: 'post', remote: 'true', class:'form-horizontal', id:'quotepartial', dataType:'script') do %>
            <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                <%= button_tag 'Test', type:'submit' %>                   
            </div>
<% end %>
```

When the Test button is clicked, it calls the above controller/method successfully. The response appears to be javascript:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:17179
Content-Type:text/javascript; charset=utf-8
Date:Sun, 16 Oct 2016 18:43:34 GMT
Etag:W/"ebb18d0a217aad163e6d40f7a75b0780"
Server:WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.3.1/2016-04-26)
Set-Cookie:_myapp_session=T2lqWG5uVmFPcGVJRjJpZndOa2NTYldEN1gyWHg3aXFvRytVRTVsanB0ZTRudWVuQ2J0MXArbjdMV2pLU0pmNEJmNDRpM2RVSkpwYlRTNWI0NWZ5d211UDh4OG8zZWVHYUZ0RTBoeDRSVDRvczA3NXVsOGU4WGx6ZlE0S1FxN1JVNDVBTXNzUGM0T0I1QUIycXJYV2x6d3Q5NkYrSTVpZGk4bTNqcVkzVWh4aW16ZndzeXRybXBZN0NOY0FKdjlOLS1nMVI2bGphMTFvZE53YXlqTXM1LzlnPT0%3D--51c4309a8d04d2af6ea16050a9bf2088d6cedbd1; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Id:68894ccf-9ee2-4157-ad88-f5440c29cd5d
X-Runtime:0.010372
X-Xss-Protection:1; mode=block
```

But the javascript doesn't execute when it returns. It is just printed out in the browser. It is as if the data-remote="true" isn't triggering an Ajax call but normal submit behavior is occurring.

This is from the Rails log, confirming js is being returned (vs html):

```
  Rendering quote/price.js.erb
  Rendered quote/_price.html.erb (2.2ms)
  Rendered quote/price.js.erb (6.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 14ms (Views: 10.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

My price.js.erb looks like this:

```
html = '<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "quote/price") %>';
$('#basicarea').html(html);
$('#quotewindow').css("display","block");
```

Controller code:

```
class QuoteController < ApplicationController

    def price
        if request.xhr?
            logger.info "Ajax";
        else
            logger.info "not ajax";
        end
        respond_to :js
    end
end
```

What should I check for? I wish the above javascript to execute when it returns, not display as text in the browser.

Elsewhere in the app, I have a separate button that I watch for the click event:

```
$('#newquote').on('click', function () {
    $.get('/home/newquote');
});
```

This returns javascript which executes successfully, so although the approach is different (jQuery $.get vs. using submit button with data-remote="true"), I know I can get javascript returned to execute in other cases. It tells me I don't have an environment/config issue.

Comment: The only thing that stands out for me is `dataType:'script'` ... try removing that

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that and it didn't help.

Comment: what does the controller action look like?

Comment: I've added controller code up in main post. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry. Don't know what else to suggest. Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks for trying.

Comment: I wonder if there's a silent error. In the dev tools copy the javascript response and paste it into the console and see what you get. I.e paste and run the rendered version of what's in `price.js.erb`

Comment: Try disabling `turbolinks` if you have that.

Comment: Maybe try replace `button_tag 'Test', type:'submit'` with `submit_tag 'Test'`

Comment: Subltletree, I get this: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of null. Sajan, I do not have turbolinks. Oleksandr, thanks but did not change things.

Answer (score 0):

I finally gave up trying to figure it out. I have handled the Ajax call directly rather than relying on data-remote to make an Ajax call. Here's the workaround:

```
  $('#quotepartial').submit(function () {  
    $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, 'script');  
    return false;  
  });
```